# App is crashing .. found the explanation with the logcat but don't know why

Tags: android, layout, crash, textview

Code:

```
        package com.example.theball;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
        private SensorManager sensorManager;
        private Sensor accelerometer;
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private long lastUpdate;
        AnimatedView animatedView = null;
        ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        public static int x;
        public static int y;
        public static final int width = 50;
        public static final int height = 50;
        public boolean firstDraw = true;
        private int screen_width; 
        private int screen_height; 
        private int sensorX;
        private Timer t;
        private int TimeCounter = 0;
        private int sensorY;
        private int score = 0;
        @Override        
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            accelerometer = sensorManager
                    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
            animatedView = new AnimatedView(this);
            setContentView(animatedView);
            t=new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {                 
                            TimeCounter++;      
                        }
                       });
                    }
            }, 0, 1000); 
        }
            public static class MainActivity extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
          TextView highscore_int = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.highscore_int );
           SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           score = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
          highscore_int.setText("Highscore:" + score +" seconds."); 
          return v;
    }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            super.onResume();
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
                sensorY = (int) event.values[1];
                sensorX = (int) event.values[0];
                x -= sensorX*3;
                y += sensorY*3;
                if(x <= 0 || x >= screen_width || y <= 0 || y >= screen_height) { 
                    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                     int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);  
                     if( TimeCounter > oldScore ){
                        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                        edit.putInt("key", TimeCounter);
                        edit.commit(); }
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, YouLost.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
        }
        public class AnimatedView extends ImageView { 

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            Point size = new Point(); 
            static final int width = 50; 
            static final int height = 50; 
            @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
            public AnimatedView(Context context) { 
            super(context); 
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub 
            display.getSize(size); 
            screen_width = size.x; 
            screen_height = size.y; 
            mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape()); 
            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23); 
            mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height); 
            }
            @Override 
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
            mDrawable.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height); 
            if(firstDraw) { 
            x = screen_width / 2; 
            y = screen_height / 2; 
            firstDraw = false; 
            } 
            mDrawable.draw(canvas); 
            invalidate(); 
            } 
            }
}
```

My new problem is , at the Eclipse Graphical Layout I can see the text but at my device I can't.

I don't know why does it happen,anyway, my text set to black and my background is white so it's not the problem.

Comment: can you paste your layout file as well? it seems that your textView is null..

Comment: check your MainActivity line no 76. null value is getting pass.

Comment: show your full onCreate() code

Comment: thats neat representation, can you post the xml and its name, make sure what the setContentView in onCreate references the same one

Comment: paste line number 76 of your main activity .

Comment: @OferM 

Added the xml file, if needed I will add more things.
And yes, my setContentView is the same one:             setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

Comment: @user2450263 See comment.

Comment: @DevCarlsberg The line is there -_- its also down after the code.

Comment: please provide the full onCreate method.

Comment: since u are using fragment, i think this may help u. [findViewById returns NULL when using Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469283/findviewbyid-returns-null-when-using-fragment)

Comment: check both onCreate() and onCreateView() , if you are inflating the fragment_main in the latter then need to shift the rootview.findViewById in onCreateView before you return the rootview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

textview `highscore_int`  is null because you are referencing `highscore_int`  from `fragment_main.xml` you will get null because in your activity you are using `activity's layout`

So use `highscore_int`  in `onCreateView` of your fragment inflate the view

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

then use the view to find the textview

```
TextView highscore_int = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.highscore_int );
```

i.e.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
          TextView highscore_int = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.highscore_int );
           SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           score = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
          highscore_int.setText("Highscore:" + score +" seconds."); 
          return v;
    }
```

Comment: It's cleaning the error but still not responding because of other thing :(

Comment: @user3784668 Post new question with new problem and if existing problem solved then accept the answer.

Comment: Yeah thank you :) one and half hour to next question :(

Comment: Emm I got an other problem now.. at my Eclipse graphical layout I can see the textview but I can't see it at my device... I put the text as "12312312" but in my device you will see nothing.

Comment: @user3784668 edit your question with oncreate method of activity.

Comment: @user3784668 implement onCreateView method in your fragment class,and override it,as I suggest.

Comment: @user3784668 hmmm..... onCreateView  is method of fragment class,so implement textview initialization code in fragment,instead of activity.

Comment: Well never mind, I guess it's not your problem.. I will open a new topic.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is based on the word `fragment_main.xml`. I guess the code you pasted is from your activity and the layout is based in your fragment. That means you can only call `findViewById()` within your fragment class.

Override the fragment method `onCreateView()` and get the highscore TextView there. Move the code there as well:

```
//onCreateView() of your fragment
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, null);
    highscore_int = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.highscore_int);

    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    score = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
    highscore_int.setText("Highscore:" + score +" seconds.");

    // You lost
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int oldScore = prefs.getInt("key", 0);  
    if( TimeCounter > oldScore ) {
        Editor edit = prefs.edit();
        edit.putInt("key", TimeCounter);
        edit.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: "mView cannot be resolved to a variable" , plus, it's asking me to remove the override.

Comment: Sorry, mView was from the code I copied. I will edit the code. For the Override: you might want to check that you have it in your Fragment class and that your Java Level is 6, otherwise you get that message (which is based on Java 4 afaik).

Answer (score 0):

because `prefs.getInt("key", 0);` is returning null and is being stored in score

**Use this**

```
score = 0;
if(prefs.getInt("key", 0) != null){
   score = prefs.getInt("key", 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not working, 
the line ' if(prefs.getInt("key", 0) != null){ ' gets an error but no suggestions available