# Android: Detect when Fragment from ViewPager gets visible inside Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

I have `Activity` with `ViewPager`. There is a button in the Activity that should change it's visibility depending on which item (fragment) is shown on the screen.

**Problem:** I can't access the button from within fragment [because findViewById() call returns null when invoked from the inside of fragment code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10469283/2065796). I also thought I could [notify activity about fragment state change](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) but the code from the documentation is already deprecated.

**Question:** How to change a button within an activity when a particular fragment appears/disappears on the screen?

Note: Getting a current fragment is not a problem. I need to **detect that fragment is changed**.

Comment: You can get the Activity's view inside a Fragment. I suppose this is what you want to do. Is it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the current Fragment instance in the viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609261/getting-the-current-fragment-instance-in-the-viewpager)

Comment: @UmangBurman unfortunately `getActivity().findViewById(id)` returns null, otherwise I would not open this question.

Comment: @JeelVankhede getting the current fragment has never been a problem, but I need **to detect that the fragment has changed**.

Comment: It's the same thing, you can detect that from `addOnPageChangeListener()`. I marked it duplicate because of this only.

Comment: **Please explain why voting down.**

Comment: Thank you. I'm not quite sure why it is the same. I am actually asking about detecting fragment change and not about getting current fragment. I guess using `addOnPageChangeListener` is just one of the ways of implementing "current fragment" functionality. Among 28 answers there is only one that touches `addOnPageChangeListener` and I can hardly imagine how it relates to my question. Though @CommonsWare has provided perfect solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a subclass of [`SimpleOnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener) inside your activity (e.g., as an anonymous inner class). In that subclass, override `onPageSelected()` and update the button visibility based on the selected page index. Then call [`addOnPageChangeListener()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)) on your `ViewPager`, supplying an instance of the `SimpleOnPageChangeListener` subclass.

Now, on every page change in the pager, `onPageSelected()` will be called, and you can update the button visibility based on the page.